# How to hide certain characters in Javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I would like to know, if there is a way to hide certain characters in string, but not replace.
So, for example

```
let a = 'Hallo';
let b = a.replace('a', ' ');
alert(b);
```

this code will alert `H llo` instead `Hallo`.

Is there any function that really hide (don't display character, but don't replace it (so, we can't see this character, but it exists still there)) ?

Comment: How and where are you using the result string? If it is used in HTML then just wrap the characters in a `span` with CSS `visibility` set to `hidden`.

Comment: Just save the contents in 2 different variables one with hide and one without...

Comment: Yea use two variables. Other wise you for display you need to wrap the letter in html tags and set style or class around the letter which is much more annoying.

Answer (score 0):

Extending on ibrahim mahrir's comment, you could create a hidden class as follows:

```
<p>Such a nifty string, wi<span class="hidden">th</span> 
some l<span class="hidden">e</span>tters missing</p>
```

Then some javascript could do this:

```
<script>
var targets = document.querySelectorAll(".hidden");

function hideLetters() {
    targets.style.visibility = "hidden";
}

hideLetters();
</script>
```

By putting it in a function like this, you could dynamically hide them. Say a user clicks a button:

```
<button id="hider">Hide letters</button>

<script>
var hider = document.querySelector("#hider");

hider.addEventListener("click", hideLetters);
</script>
```

And then a function to show them, if you like.

```
<script>
function showLetters() {
    targets.style.visibility = "visible";
}
</script>
```

Comment: Don't use JavaScript to set the style of a **CSS** class. Use a CSS stylesheet for CSS.

Comment: The point of using JavaScript is that it can be changed by script rather than hardcoded in HTML. Though you do have a point that if the content is absolutely static, a pure CSS solution is best. Also, the OP tagged it with `javascript`.

Comment: @Naltroc I think what @HereticMonkey was suggesting was to use the following CSS `.hideable.hidden { visibility: hidden; }`, then via JS (a click) add the class `hidden` to all `hideable` elements to hide them. But the code wouldn't have been as simple.

Answer (score 0):

```js
let div = document.getElementById("div");

let str = "Ibrahim Mahrir plays Hallo!";

div.innerHTML = str.replace(/a/g, "<span class='hidden'>$&</span>");
```

```css
#div {
  margin-top: 30px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #fffbec;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #d89d9d;
}

.hidden {
  visibility: hidden;
}

#div:hover .hidden {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
Hover over the div to see the missing characters:

<div id="div"></div>
```